# Creating an expanded matrix with interpolated data in R

Tags: r, matrix, interpolation, apply

I have a data frame that has annual data for population by MSA.  They are organized as follows:

```
 MSA    FIPS  x1969 x1970 x1971 .... x2012
Akron   123    12    14    17  ....   22
Miami   234    23    20    24  ....   29
etc.
```

I need to reshape the data into

```
 MSA FIPS Year Data
 Akron 123 1969 12
 Akron 123 1970 14
 Akron 123 1971 17
```

...

I can do this using "melt", but I also want to interpolate these annual data to include quarterly data points for the full time series.  So, how best to create the quarterly (interpolated) matrix on the fly?

I can do this using a loop over the rows of the first matrix above and then use melt to reshape the new data, but I've been asked to slap myself anytime I catch myself building explicitly coded loops.

I've been tinkering with "apply", but it creates a list of lists -- which would then require assembling the final data frame.

I can feel a simple solution must be out there.

Thanks, Chris.

Comment: Do you have one dataset with annual data or two- another with quarterly data?

Comment: One data set that is annual like the examples above.  I want to interpolate the missing three quarters from 1969 to 1970 and from 1970 to 1972 etc.  The current data is n (msa) x m (years); I want it to be n (msa) x q (quarters).  How to I create the new matrix or data frame?  I can melt/reshape before or after creating the quarters.  Thank you!

Comment: I may have misunderstood your question.  From the data you showed, it seems like you wanted to `disaggregate` the annual to `quarterly`.  In that case, specialized packages like `tempdisagg` would be better.  As I mentioned in the post, there are options.

Comment: Got it.  Again, thanks.  The options are overwhelming at times.  This is a new language with a rich vocabulary.

Answer (score 0):

May be you could try `td` from `tempdisagg`

```
library(tempdisagg)
library(reshape2)
library(zoo)

dM <- transform(melt(df, id.var=c('MSA', 'FIPS')), 
            variable=as.numeric(gsub('^x', '', variable)))

res <- lapply(split(dM, dM$MSA), function(x) {
           val <- ts(x$value, start=x$variable[1], end=x$variable[nrow(x)])
           val2 <-predict(td(val~1, to='quarterly', method='uniform')) 
          #change the options as needed
          data.frame(yearQtr= as.yearqtr(time(val2)), val=val2)})
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(MSA = c("Akron", "Miami"), FIPS = c(123L, 234L
 ), x1969 = c(12L, 23L), x1970 = c(14L, 20L), x1971 = c(17L, 24L
)), .Names = c("MSA", "FIPS", "x1969", "x1970", "x1971"), class = "data.frame",
row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun!  I learned about gsub, about split, and am now tinkering with ts.  I've already had a good day with R, thanks.  But, the output is below (there is no interpolation between the original data points and they appear to be off (from 12, 14, and 17 in the original to the output below.  Again, thank you.  I'll keep working on it.  Snip here --> > res
$Akron
   yearQtr  val
1  1969 Q1 3.00
2  1969 Q2 3.00
3  1969 Q3 3.00
4  1969 Q4 3.00
5  1970 Q1 3.50
6  1970 Q2 3.50
7  1970 Q3 3.50
8  1970 Q4 3.50
9  1971 Q1 4.25
10 1971 Q2 4.25
11 1971 Q3 4.25
12 1971 Q4 4.25

Answer (score 0):

This builds on @akrun earlier:

```
#His data frame build:

df <- structure(list(MSA = c("Akron", "Miami"), FIPS = c(123L, 234L),
      x1969 = c(12L, 23L), x1970 = c(14L, 20L), x1971 = c(17L, 24L)),
     .Names = c("MSA", "FIPS", "x1969", "x1970", "x1971"), class = "data.frame",
     row.names = c(NA, -2L))

#His set up:

dM <- transform(melt(df, id.var=c('MSA', 'FIPS')),
        variable=as.numeric(gsub('^x', '', variable)))

#My variation on his lapply:

res <- lapply(split(dM, dM$MSA), function(x) {
       xseq=seq(min(x$variable),max(x$variable),by=.25)
       val <- approx(x$variable,x$value,xout=xseq)
       data.frame(yearQtr=xseq,val=val$y)})

df.new <- do.call(rbind.data.frame,res)
```

It's not quite perfect, but I'll get back to it later.  We're close.  Thank you @akrun